# Scale date axis of XYPlot to a fixed interval

Tags: java, plot, scale, jfreechart

In Java project, I used JFreeChart 1.0.19 version and `XYPlot` to draw lines on plot.

I want scale `xAxis` (Date axis) as date in example - 10:00:05, 10:00:05, 10:00:10, 10:00:15…—scaling for every 5 seconds.

But now when user start with 10:00:03 time, it looks as 10:00:03, 10:00:08, 10:00:13, 10:00:18…

I want that always be scaled of 5 seconds as 10:00:05, 10:00:05, 10:00:10, 10:00:15 and be independently of start time, how to set it?

I configurated domain axis(time axis) as below:

```
domainAxis.setAutoRange(true);
domainAxis.setAutoTickUnitSelection(true);
domainAxis.setLowerMargin(0.001);
domainAxis.setUpperMargin(0.001);
```

`domainAxis` is a object of `ValueAxis`

My plot looks like [image]
as You see the time values are 11:21:57, 11:22:07, 11:22:17 etc. I want that always should be 11:21:55, 11:22:05, 11:22:15 etc.

Comment: You didn't provide any code, but seems like you'd just check the clock seconds with a `seconds % 5` before doing any recording.

Comment: But what about first four seconds ? There will be no Dates, now is autoscaling

Comment: Maybe any suggestions how to set it for plot ?

Comment: I don't know JFreeChart, otherwise I'd post an answer. I would say you have a few options, though. If possible, don't start until seconds ends in 5. You could also set the scale to `(5 - (n%5))` where `n` is the current second, then set it to 5 after `5-(n%5)` seconds. Third, you can just decide it's not a big deal and go with it :-)

Comment: I've elaborated below. For more specific guidance, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Answer (score 1):

Because `domainAxis` is an instance of [`DateAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc_old/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateAxis.html), you can use `setTickUnit()` to specify a [`DateTickUnit`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateTickUnit.html) having the desired `unitType` and `multiple`. In this fragment, the interval is five seconds, and the format includes seconds:

```
domainAxis.setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.SECOND, 5));
domainAxis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"));
```

[image]

Comment: `ValueAxis` do not contain method `setTickUnit()`

Comment: A `DateAxis` _is a_ concrete subclass of the abstract class, `ValueAxis`; your question mentions both, so you might want to check. For more specific guidance, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.